# How do you create general personalized functions in C and then include them in your program?

Tags: c, function, header

I'm  a beginner to C, but I've had a bit of experience with some other programing languages like Ruby and Python.  I would very much like to create some of my own functions in C that I could use in any of my programs that just make life easier, however I'm a little bit confused about how to do this.

From what I understand the first part of this process is to create a header file that contains all of your prototypes, and I understand that, however from what I understand it is frowned upon to include anything other than declarations in your header files, so would you also need to create a .c file that contained the actual code and then #include that in all your programs along with the header file?  But if so, why would you need a header file in the first place, since defining a function also declares it?

Finally, what should you put in the main() function of your header file?  Do you just leave it blank, or do you not include it?

Thanks!

Comment: SO is not the proper place for a tutorial about separate compilation. Please read some such as https://www.cs.utah.edu/~zachary/isp/tutorials/separate/separate.html and come back with specific answer and code to debug if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of a function lets the compiler know that at link time such a function will be available. The definition of the function provides that implementation, and additionally it *also* serves as the declaration. There is no harm in having multiple declarations, but only one implementation can be provided. Also, at least one declaration (or the only implementation) must come before any use of the function - this alone makes forward declarations necessary in cases where two functions call one another (both cannot be before the other).

So, if you have the implementation:

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

The corresponding declaration is simply:

```
int foo(int a, int b);
```

(The argument names do not matter in the declaration, i.e., they can be omitted or different than in the implementation. In fact you could declare only `int foo();` and it would work for the above function, but this is mainly a legacy thing and not recommended. Note that to declare a function that takes no arguments, put `void` in the argument list, e.g., `int bar(void);`)

There are a number of reasons why you would want to have separate headers with only the declaration:

- The implementation may be in a separate file, which allows for organisation of code into manageable pieces, and may be compiled by itself and need not be recompiled unless that file has changed - in large projects where the total compilation time can be an hour it would be absurd to re-compile everything for a small change.
- The implementation source may not be available, e.g., in case of a closed-source proprietary library.
- The implementation may be in a different language with a compatible calling convention.

For practical details on how to write code in multiple files and how to use libraries, please consult a book or tutorial on C programming. As for `main`, you need not declare it in a header unless you are specifically calling `main` from another function - the convention of C programs is to call `main` as `int main(int, char**)` at start of the execution.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling, each .c-file (or .cpp-file) will be compiled to an own binary first.
If one binary file is using functions from another,
it just knows "there is something outside named xyz" at that time.
Then the linker will put them together in one file and rewrite the parts of each file
which are using functions of other files,
so that they actually know where to find the used functions.

What will happen if you put code in a .h file:
At compilation time, each included h-file in a c-file will be integrated in the c-file.
If you have code for xyz in a h-file and you´re including it in more thana one c-file,
each of this compiled c-files will have a xyz.  Then, the linker will be confused...
So, function code have to be in a own c file.

Why use a h-file at all?
Because, if you call xyz in your code, how should the compiler know
if this is a function of another c-file (and which parameters...)
or an error because xyz does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for header files in c are for when you need the same code in multiple scripts. So if you are just repeated the same code in one script then yes it would be easier to just use a function. Also for header files, yes you would need to include a .c file for all the computations.